# DNS A record keeps changing

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have 2 Windows 2012 servers. One is a Domain Controller and the other is a Web Server. DNS is hosted on both of these servers.

I have deleted the default A record and made a new one with the IP of my webserver. After about 10 minutes, a new record was generated with the IP of my DC. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop. Don't do this. If you've named your Active Directory the same as your external web presence, you've goofed. I've [blogged about how to properly name your AD](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810122929/http://www.mdmarra.com/2012/11/why-you-shouldnt-use-local-in-your.html). You should read it. It's about .local mostly, but also touches on split-DNS which you've created here.

This except is shamelessly stolen from my blog:

> The correct way to name an Active Directory domain is to create a
> subdomain that is the delegation of a parent domain that you have
> registered and have control over. As an example, if I ever started a
> consulting business and used the Internet-facing website mdmarra.com
> as my company's site, I should name my Active Directory domain
> ad.mdmarra.com or internal.mdmarra.com, or something similar. You want
> to avoid making up a TLD like .local and you also want to avoid the
> headache of using mdmarra.com for the Internet-facing zone and the
> internal zone.

Your domain controllers will always register A records automatically for the root of your AD domain. This is why it's best practice if you web site is `example.com` to name your AD `corp.example.com` or `ad.example.com`

There are a few workarounds for this:

1. Run IIS (or another web server) on your DC and redirect requests on :80 of :443 to `www.example.com` which will be your web server.
2. Train your internal users to go to `www.example.com` instead of just `example.com`
3. Throw your AD away and start over with a properly named one.

1 and 2 are bandaids. 3 is the fix.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize that I should not name it as the same as my domain.